# Upsampling Tensor for TensorRT

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

The tensorflow model is converted to TensorRT and Tensorflow's ResizeArea(upsample in the picture) need to implement plugin.
[image]

So ResizeArea is implemented in CUDA.
My TensorRT input is NCHW format.

```
uff_path = model_to_uff(model_path)
parser.register_input(ModelData.INPUT_NAME, (3, height, width), trt.UffInputOrder.NCHW)
parser.register_output(ModelData.OUTPUT_NAME)
parser.parse(uff_path, network)
```

So my CUDA code is implemented NCHW resampling.
I like to make sure my resampling format is correct.

**Method_1**

NCHW resizearea(4 times upsampling) sample.

```
channel_1      channel_2        channel_3
3,1,2,0,       0,4,3,1,         2,0,2,3,
3,0,1,2,       0,1,2,1,         2,0,4,2,
4,1,2,2,       1,3,2,4,         2,3,4,2,

channel_1                         channel_2                         channel_3  
3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,  0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,  0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,  0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,  0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,  1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,  2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,  1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,  2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,  1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,  2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,  1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,  2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
```

Each pixel is 4 times upsampled(for example, first pixel 3 is upsample 4 times horizontally and vertically). That is considered as NCHW format upsampling.

**Method_2**

Another way implemented is considered upsampling in NHWC format.
[image]

[image]

3-channel data (83,86,77) is upsampled horizontally and vertically.

Is Method_1 is correct way of NCHW upsampling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking some time. The issue was solved. TensorRT works in NCHW format. Tensorflow model is in NHWC format. So in my plugin, need to work upsampling in NCHW format but output needs to change as NHWC format so that it can interface to next Tensorflow operations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems method 1 is ok, since TensorRT expects CHW as said in [the docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-developer-guide/index.html#import_tf_c), NHWC is a TF format, are you considering `AlignCorners` in your plugin layer? Also note that the resizing is nearest neighbor, in pytorch I used onnx-trt to do bilinear interpolation, which gave better results (in the case of segmentation, maybe for your case nn is ok).